Replicating tables across databases in RDS
I have 2 databases on an RDS instance called A and B. Both are of two separate micro-services.
By mistake while deploying the new microservice instead of pointing to B. I pointed to A. So all the tables and data related to new microservice got created in A instead of B. Now when I am planning for a data migration of the related tables to B i need to drop some FK constraints as there is a lot of data for a smoother transition. AWS is not allowing me to do that as my user is not a superuser. How do I proceed in this case.
Below is the query that I am trying to execute
ALTER TABLE template DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;


ERROR:  permission denied: "RI_ConstraintTrigger_a_132889" is a system trigger
SQL state: 42501

I tried to connect to the database as the superuser but its not letting me connect
